# Changing pixel color in for-loop

Tags: python, image, opencv, image-processing

```
import cv
import cv2
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.image as mpimg
import numpy as np
import Image
cam = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
s,img1 = cam.read()
height, width, depth = img1.shape
print height, width
for i in range(0,height):
   for j in range(0,width):
      if (img1[i, j] <= [25,25,25]).all():
        img1[i, j] = [255, 0, 128]
      elif ((img1[i, j] > [25,25,25]).all() and (img1[i, j] <= [50,50,50]).all()):
          img1[i,j] = [255, 255, 128]
      elif ((img1[i, j] > [50,50,50]).all() and (img1[i, j] <= [75,75,75]).all()):
          img1[i,j] = [255, 128, 0]
      elif ((img1[i, j] > [75,75,75]).all() and (img1[i, j] <= [100,100,100]).all()):
          img1[i,j] = [0, 255, 0]
      elif ((img1[i, j] > [100,100,100]).all() and (img1[i, j] <= [125,125,125]).all()):
          img1[i,j] = [68, 128, 251]      
      elif ((img1[i, j] > [125,125,125]).all() and (img1[i, j] <= [150,150,150]).all()):
          img1[i,j] = [0, 255, 255]
      elif ((img1[i, j] > [150,150,150]).all() and (img1[i, j] <= [175,175,175]).all()):
          img1[i,j] = [0, 0, 255]
      elif ((img1[i, j] > [175,175,175]).all() and (img1[i, j] <= [200,200,200]).all()):
          img1[i,j] = [128, 128, 128]
      elif ((img1[i, j] > [200,200,200]).all() and (img1[i, j] <= [225,225,225]).all()):
          img1[i,j] = [0, 0, 0]
      elif ((img1[i, j] > [225,225,225]).all() and (img1[i, j] <= [255,255,255]).all()):
          img1[i,j] = [255, 255, 255]
      else:
         img1[i,j] = [0, 60, 0]
      j=j+1
   i=i-1
m=1
while m<2:
  cv2.imshow('pseudocolor',img1)
  cv2.waitKey(10)
```

while running this else statement works more 
i.e. what should i do to give different color to pixel values such as [10, 50, 2],[23,3,167] etc
there is some problem relating the assignment of pixel values.....
not able to fetch some pixels,that is why the else statement works more number of times

Comment: please look at cv2.LUT(). you basically do a 1d(grayscale intensity) lookup in your code above.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
import cv
import cv2
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.image as mpimg
import numpy as np
import Image
cam = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
s,img1 = cam.read()
imgg1=img1
height, width, depth = img1.shape
print height, width
for i in range(0,height):
   for j in range(0,width):
      if (img1[i, j] <= [25,25,25]).all():
        img1[i,j] = [255, 255, 255]
        imgg1[i, j] = [255, 0, 128]
      elif (img1[i, j] <= [50,50,50]).all():
          img1[i,j] = [255, 255, 255]
          imgg1[i,j] = [255, 255, 128]
      elif (img1[i, j] <= [75,75,75]).all():
          img1[i,j] = [255, 255, 255]
          imgg1[i,j] = [255, 128, 0]
      elif (img1[i, j] <= [100,100,100]).all():
          img1[i,j] = [255, 255, 255]
          imgg1[i,j] = [0, 255, 0]
      elif (img1[i, j] <= [125,125,125]).all():
          img1[i,j] = [255, 255, 255]
          imgg1[i,j] = [68, 128, 251]      
      elif (img1[i, j] <= [150,150,150]).all():
          img1[i,j] = [255, 255, 255]
          imgg1[i,j] = [0, 255, 255]
      elif (img1[i, j] <= [175,175,175]).all():
          img1[i,j] = [255, 255, 255]
          imgg1[i,j] = [0, 0, 255]
      elif (img1[i, j] <= [200,200,200]).all():
          img1[i,j] = [255, 255, 255]
          imgg1[i,j] = [128, 128, 128]
      elif (img1[i, j] <= [225,225,225]).all():
          img1[i,j] = [255, 255, 255]
          imgg1[i,j] = [0, 0, 0]
      elif (img1[i, j] < [255,255,255]).all():
          img1[i,j] = [255, 255, 255]
          imgg1[i,j] = [255, 255, 255]
      else:
         imgg1[i,j] = [0, 60, 0]
      j=j+1
   i=i-1
m=1
while m<2:
  cv2.imshow('pseudocolor',imgg1)
  cv2.waitKey(10)
```

Above program excecution seems to take about 7-8 minutes.
Is there any method to increase the excecution speed.

Comment: What you are essentially doing is changing from one pixel color to another, right? Check 3D look up tables and colour look-up table. Might help you a bit. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/3D_lookup_table / http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Colour_look-up_table